# How could I have different scaling by yAxisID

Tags: javascript, chart.js

My chart is made of a few sub charts that share one a timeline on the x axis (`xAxis`) and have multiple y scales, grouping datasets by their `yAxisID`. The axes are located one on top of the other.

These sub charts have very different value ranges, all loaded from data. For example one of them is now from 0 to 22,000, while the other from 50 to 53.

How could I implement individual height in pixels/cm/percent of each sub chart?

Comment: Thank you @Heretic Monkey  for the attention you gave to my question. While upper casing of I is a definite improvement, words I've used like yAxisID are exact names of variables within the chart.js toolkit, that I was asking about. That's why i'm personally not using keyboard autocorrection. My question describes my chart scales, my data, my aim I couldn't achieve, and what solution I've vainly tried.

Comment: I apologize for my overzealous correction, I think editing it and formatting it as code was the correct decision.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, if you could open my question, i wish to post a solution.

Answer (score 1):

may be this helps

- Use the `distribution: 'linear'` setting on each scale to disable any autoscaling. This will let you control the density explicitly.
- Set a different `min` and `max` value on each y-axis scale to determine the range. A smaller range will spread the values out over more pixels.

Comment: thank you @newlearner. i found the solution. setting `stackWeight` to the various scales allows us to get different pixel density per value.

Comment: @alex that's great do Share the solution here

Comment: the solution is setting different `stackWeight` for each scale. the bigger the `stackWeight` value, the more pixels height will be allocated to each value in that scale. thanks again @newlearner. ps the question was closed due to some misspelling. if you could vote to reopen it i'll post this as an answer, not as a comment.